# Determiners in English sentence. Is it ok to say?

Tags: american-english, british-english, determiners, zero-article

Do I need any determiners in the sentence below in general statement?

> Strong winds destroy homes.

Is it ok to say in English in specific situation?

> The strong wind destroyed the homes in North Carolina.

I mean mostly the determiners in this sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are correct, but their meanings are different.

In the first sentence, you're simply stating **a fact**. You're saying that *destroying homes* is what *strong winds* do. There's no reference to specific winds or specific homes in that sentence.

In your second sentence, however, you're referring to **a specific event**. A wind that you previously mentiond in the text or that is clear from the context (***the*** strong wind) has destroyed the homes in North Carolina. In this sentence, you're not saying that this is what all strong winds do. You're simply referring to an event that has occurred.

Comment: A by-the-way question. Would "*The strong wind destroyed North Carolina homes.*" be the exact equivalent?  Thanks.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. *The homes in North Carolina* implies that **all** homes were destroyed. Without the definite article, *North Carolina homes* would imply that not all, but a certain amount of the homes in North Carolina were destroyed.

Comment: @Sander I'd say that *the homes in NC* implies a previously identified group of homes in NC, distinguished from a previously identified set of homes not in NC or from a superset of homes both in NC and elsewhere.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, but if the group has not yet been identified, wouldn't it sound as though all of the houses were destroyed?

Comment: @Sander But in this sort of context you don't use *the* except to designate a group that has already been identified or is identified in the same NP.

Comment: @Sander, I disagree. _the homes in NC_ implies a previously identified group, not all.